# I want to add a tax-ID field in registration form and upon submission, perform a lookup by tax-ID

Tags: user-registration

I want to allow visitors to register to my site. I want to add tax ID field in the form. Upon submission, I want to check if the user belongs to a list (which has been imported in a custom table)and if yes, assign him a role.

How do you propose I should handle all that?

Thanks.

Comment: Will all of the users on the list be the same role?

Comment: No, some users a good customers and hence get a high role while some other users get a lower role.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting area to work through ...

If you have the user's `tax id` and you know the role they need, then why not pre-register them and then send them an invite to login?

From my experience with WordPress, it's easier to bulk add users and have them partial registered.  You can [import users with a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-multiple-users/) like this.

You may already have read .. there is a bit of a post on WordPress.org about [having 2 registration forms](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-register-subscribers-and-authors) ... one form will change the users role after registration.

If everyone who registers has to be an 'author' or have special privileges, then change the default role from Subscriber to Author (WordPress Admin > Settings )
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Sorry no, my users prefer the approach outlined in my original question.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, though, the submission with the GET parameter and the update of the user's meta field is a neat trick. Thanks.